# Matrix vs scalar expression mismatch when using NumPy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Whilst running a simulation of a discrete-time system, I'm having trouble getting the equivalent scalar expressions of the original matrix equation to generate identical output (I need to convert all matrix expressions to scalars in order to implement the code in my embedded C project).

Please run the function with the following input parameters.

```
torque_sim_ctest(0.006,0,0.01,12)
```

Click the hyperlinks to see screen-shots of the expected output computed using the matrix  expression ([correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EOokF.png)) vs. the output using the (supposedly) equivalent scalar expressions ([incorrect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vApRt.png)).

Below is the code, which should give the [correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EOokF.png) output by default. To test the scalar computations, please comment line # 98 (`qo_next = np.dot(Ado,qo) + np.dot(Bo,np.vstack([hallf, v[:,k]]))`), and uncomment 100 through 102, run the script, and then call the function with the same parameters as shown above.

Lines to uncomment in tandem with the `qo_next = ...` matrix expression highlighted above:

```
#            qo_next[0] = Ado[0,0]*qo[0] + Ado[0,1]*qo[1] + Ado[0,2]*qo[2] + Bo[0,0]*hallf
#            qo_next[1] = Ado[1,0]*qo[0] + Ado[1,1]*qo[1] + Ado[1,2]*qo[2] + Bo[1,0]*hallf + Bo[1,1]*v[:,k]
#            qo_next[2] = Ado[2,0]*qo[0] + Ado[2,1]*qo[1] + Ado[2,2]*qo[2] + Bo[2,0]*hallf
```

I would really appreciate it if someone could point out the bug in the scalar version of the code and help me fix this (numerical?) issue. Thank you!

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.signal as sig
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def torque_sim_ctest(K,Kp,Kd,tau_ampl):
# Example parameter values: torque_sim_ctest(0.006,0,0.01,12)

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Motor & System Parameters in continuous time:    
    bm, Jm, K_e, K_t = 1.5e-6, 3.507e-6, 12.5e-3, 12.5e-3
    R, L = 0.476, 0.334e-3
    gr, Jl, bl = 16.348, 10, 20

    Jeq, beq = Jl + Jm*gr**2, bl + bm*gr**2

    A = np.array([ [  0,  1        ],
                   [  0,  -beq/Jeq ]   ])

    Ac = np.array( [[ 0,  1,  0   ],
                    [ 0,  0,  1   ],
                    [ 0,  0,  0   ]])

    B = np.array([ [   0,      0                   ],
                   [   gr/Jeq, gr**2*K_t/(Jeq*R)   ]])

    Bc = np.array([   0,   1,   0   ]).reshape(3,1)

    C = np.array([   1,  0 ])

    Co = np.array([   1,  0,   0   ]).reshape(1,3)

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Controller update interval Tc and simulation time step Td
    Tc = 0.01
    Td = 0.1*Tc
# Now discretise the continuous-time system model    
    Ad, Bd, Cd, Dd, dt = sig.cont2discrete((A,B,C,0),Td,method='bilinear')

# Output smoothing: filter parameters
    f_ord = 2
    num, den = sig.cheby1(f_ord,5,2*np.pi*10,'low',analog=True)
    Af, Bf, Cf, Df = sig.tf2ss(num,den)
    Afd, Bfd, Cfd, Dfd, dt = sig.cont2discrete((Af,Bf,Cf,Df),Tc,
                                               method='bilinear')
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Observer Parameters
    eps = 0.01
    alph = Tc/eps
    a1, a2, a3 = 3, 3, 1
    Ho = np.array([a1, a2, a3]).reshape(3,1)
    Ao = Ac - np.dot(Ho,Co)
    D = np.diag([1, eps, eps**2])
    Do = np.zeros([3,1])
    Ado, Bdo, Cdo, Ddo, dt = sig.cont2discrete((Ao,Ho,np.linalg.inv(D),Do),
                                               alph,method='bilinear')
    Bo = np.hstack([Bdo.reshape(3,1),    Bc.reshape(3,1)])
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Total simulation steps
    n = 5001

# Define initial conditions prior to running simulation    
    x, q = np.zeros([2,n]), np.zeros([2,1])
    q_next = np.zeros([2,1])
    y, v = 0, np.zeros([1,n])
    tau_ext = np.zeros([1,n])
    hallc = 0
    qf, qf_next, hallf = np.zeros([f_ord,1]), np.zeros([f_ord,1]), 0
    qo, qo_next, xhat = np.zeros([3,1]), np.zeros([3,1]), np.zeros([3,1])

# The for loop below simulates the closed-loop system in discrete time steps Td
    print('Simulation running; please wait ...')
    for k in range(n-1):
#       External torque input with peaks at 0.5 s and 1.6 s
        tau_ext[:,k] =  tau_ampl*(0.5*np.exp(-10*(k*Td-0.5)**2) \
                        + np.exp(-5*(k*Td-1.6)**2))

#       y is the output angle in SI units (radians)
        y = gr*np.dot(C,x[:,k])
#       Conversion of rotor angle to ideal hall-count
        hallc = int(150/np.pi*y+0.5*np.sign(y))

#        Now apply a smoothing filter
#        qf_next = Afd @ qf + Bfd @ np.matrix([hallc[:,k]/gr])
#        hallf = Cf @ (qf + qf_next)

        qf_next[0] = 0.661939208333454*qf[0] - 19.836230603818*qf[1] + 0.00830969604166727*hallc/gr
        qf_next[1] = 0.00830969604166727*qf[0] + 0.90081884698091*qf[1] + 4.15484802083364e-5*hallc/gr

#        Filtered hall-count
        hallf = 1342.37547903*(qf[1] + qf_next[1])

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# State Observer & Control Law
#       Update the controller states only every Tc = 10*Td time step
        if np.mod(k,int(Tc/Td+0.5)) == 0:
            qo_next = np.dot(Ado,qo) + np.dot(Bo,np.vstack([hallf, v[:,k]]))

#            qo_next[0] = Ado[0,0]*qo[0] + Ado[0,1]*qo[1] + Ado[0,2]*qo[2] + Bo[0,0]*hallf
#            qo_next[1] = Ado[1,0]*qo[0] + Ado[1,1]*qo[1] + Ado[1,2]*qo[2] + Bo[1,0]*hallf + Bo[1,1]*v[:,k]
#            qo_next[2] = Ado[2,0]*qo[0] + Ado[2,1]*qo[1] + Ado[2,2]*qo[2] + Bo[2,0]*hallf

#            qo_next[0] = 1.40740740740741*hallf - 0.407407407407407*qo[0] + 0.296296296296296*qo[1] + 0.148148148148148*qo[2]
#            qo_next[1] = 1.03703703703704*hallf - 1.03703703703704*qo[0] + 0.481481481481481*qo[1] + 0.740740740740741*qo[2] + v[:,k]
#            qo_next[2] = 0.296296296296296*hallf - 0.296296296296296*qo[0] - 0.148148148148148*qo[1] + 0.925925925925926*qo[2]

            xhat[0] = 0.703703703703704*hallf + 0.296296296296296*qo[0] + 0.148148148148148*qo[1] + 0.0740740740740741*qo[2]
            xhat[1] = 51.8518518518519*hallf - 51.8518518518518*qo[0] + 74.0740740740741*qo[1] + 37.037037037037*qo[2]
            xhat[2] = 1481.48148148148*hallf - 1481.48148148148*qo[0] - 740.740740740741*qo[1] + 9629.62962962963*qo[2]

#            xhat = Cdo @ qo + Ddo @ np.matrix(hallf)

#       Update the control voltage v[:,k]
            v[:,k] = K*xhat[2] + Kp*hallf + Kd*xhat[1]
            if v[:,k] < 0:
                v[:,k] = 0
            elif v[:,k] >= 12:
                v[:,k] = 12

        else:
#       Wait and hold; don't update in this cycle
            qo_next = qo
            v[:,k] = v[:,k-1]
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Now calculate the system dynamics in discrete time steps Td
        q_next = np.dot(Ad,q) + np.dot(Bd,np.vstack([tau_ext[:,k], v[:,k]]))
        x[:,k+1:k+2] = q + q_next

        q = q_next

        qf[0] = qf_next[0]
        qf[1] = qf_next[1]

        qo[0] = qo_next[0]
        qo[1] = qo_next[1]
        qo[2] = qo_next[2]

# ** End For Loop **

# Plot the simulation output
# NOTE: System velocity signal is x[1,:], and position is y = x[0,:]
    print('Done.')
    tau_spr = gr*K_t/R*v[0,0:n-1]
    tau_net = tau_spr + tau_ext[0,0:n-1]
    t = np.linspace(0.0,(n-1)*Td,num=n-1)

    fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots(2,2)
    ax1[0,0].plot(t,tau_ext[0,0:n-1],'r--',t,tau_spr,'b-')
    ax1[0,0].set_xlabel('Time (s)')
    ax1[0,0].set_ylabel('Torque (N m)')
    ax1[0,0].set_title('Torque Comparison')

    ax1[0,1].plot(t,tau_ext[0,0:n-1]/tau_net,'r--',t,tau_spr/tau_net,'b-')
    ax1[0,1].set_xlabel('Time (s)')
    ax1[0,1].set_ylabel('Torque (Normalised)')
    ax1[0,1].set_title('Torque Comparison')

    ax1[1,0].step(t,v[0,0:n-1],'g-')
    ax1[1,0].set_xlabel('Time (s)')
    ax1[1,0].set_ylabel('Drive Voltage (V)')
    ax1[1,0].set_title('Motor Voltage')

    ax1[1,1].step(t,30/np.pi*x[1,0:n-1],'m-')
    ax1[1,1].set_xlabel('Time (s)')
    ax1[1,1].set_ylabel('Motor Speed (rpm)')
    ax1[1,1].set_title('Motor Speed vs Time')
```

Comment: Right off I see you creating a lot of `np.matrix` objects.  Why?  Why not `np.array`?  In doing the conversion are you taking into account the `matrix multiplication` nature of `np.matrix` `*`?  As opposed to the element wise multiplication of `ndarrays`?

Comment: I thought I needed the `np.matrix` objects to perform matrix multiplication. If I recall correctly, I'm not performing any mathematical operations directly on whole `np.array` objects (not counting individually extracted elements). I believe I also used the `@` operator exclusively to multiply non-scalar objects together.

Please let me know if the code provided fails to run as-is

Comment: `np.dot` has always been available for matrix multiplication.  In fact the `np.matrix` uses that under the cover.  For 2d arrays `@` just a syntactic convenience.

Comment: @dash-dot no, you absolutely do *not* need `np.matrix` objects to use matrix multiplication, as already explained. It is recommended to use `np.ndarray` objects instead of `np.matrix`

Comment: Your code is long enough that I won;t try to debug or comment further without a running copy.  Usually when suggesting improvements, I start with running code, and make a series of small changes, aiming to make the code clearer (to me), and of course making sure that values match. That way I can improve it without necessarily understanding the whole code.

Comment: Thanks to you both for the feedback; I have updated the code and tested it to use `np.array` objects _only_, applying reshaping as needed to ensure compatibility during matrix multiplication. The code should work by just copy-pasting into a Python editor, running the script and then calling the function using the parameters provided in the OP. The output of the default matrix version with the `qo_next = ...` assignment is the same as before, but soon as I replace it with what ought to be the scalar equivalent, the output changes. It must be a simple arithmetic error, but I can't identify it.

Answer (score 0):

Phew, I may have finally got to the bottom of my issue, even though I don't fully understand the nature of the problem with array vs. scalar assignments.

When I use the vector computation: `qo_next = np.dot(Ado,qo) + np.dot(Bo,np.vstack([hallf, v[:,k]]))`, then my implementation of the Zero-Order-Hold further down: `qo_next = qo` appears to work as one would expect.

When I convert the first assignment to a set of scalar expressions, however, it appears I must *also* do an element-by-element assignment to implement the Z.O.H., i.e.:

```
qo_next[0] = qo[0]
qo_next[1] = qo[1]
qo_next[2] = qo[2]
```

When I do that, the scalar conversion magically works and generates output equivalent to the vector version.

That was a real head-scratcher -- perhaps someone can explain to me how assignment works in Python so I can make sense of this. Thank you for reading.